# httpclient put problem

Tags: java, httpclient, put

I have been given an api which states that it requires:

> ```
> URL http://server/a/messages.xml
>
> HTTP Method POST (even though the soapui example  of this call uses PUT)
>
> Input XML
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <message>
>   <content>Post message</content>
>   <parent-id nil="true"></parent-id>
> </message>
> ```

Now i have tried to use the following code (where request body is the xml as seen above with no \r\n in)

```
PutMethod putMethod = null;
putMethod = new PutMethod(url); 
putMethod.setQueryString(requestParams);
RequestEntity rEnt = new StringRequestEntity(requestBody,"text/xml",null);
putMethod.setRequestEntity(rEnt);
statusCode = client.executeMethod(putMethod);
```

I keep getting back 500 from the status, I know it works as the soapui example (put) works.

Any ideas what small thing I am missing. (I am going to try post too)

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using POST instead, as suggested in the documentation above?

Answer (score 1):

If you get back a 500 status code, it's a server error. In theory, bad requests (even badly formed) should make the server return a 4xx status code, not make it return a status code indicating an internal fault on its side. If this server returns a 500 status code for a request you make, it indicates a problem on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Well it turned out that a POST did work, even though the SOAPUI request was a PUT.. Most odd i guess i don't understand something..

Thanks for the help